# How to Install glibc 2.32 when I already have glibc2.31

Tags: libraries, glibc

Please help me install `glibc` 2.32. Running 20.04.

Comment: Not a good idea. The libraries shipped by glibc have a lot of reverse dependencies, and an upgrade would probably trigger a need to rebuild quite a few other packages. So if a later glibc is important for some reason, the best option you have is to upgrade to 20.10 and then 21.04.

Answer (score 23):

If you need glibc version other than the one shipped with ubuntu, one way is to install manually to a temp location in your `$HOME`. (installing in `/usr` would mess up with existing glibc in case something goes wrong)

```
mkdir $HOME/glibc/ && cd $HOME/glibc
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libc/glibc-2.32.tar.gz
tar -xvzf glibc-2.32.tar.gz
mkdir build 
mkdir glibc-2.32-install
cd build
~/glibc/glibc-2.32/configure --prefix=$HOME/glibc/glibc-2.32-install
make
make install
```

Now you should have glibc 2.32 installed in the installation directory check with `~/glibc/glibc-2.32 install/bin/ldd --version`

Comment: These are awesome steps, thank you! I was able to successfully build GLIBC_2.33. I basically replaced 2.32 with 2.33 in your steps, worked perfectly. I hit one bison missing error, resolved by install bison, followed these steps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320370/installation-of-flex-and-bison-in-ubuntu

Comment: I was following the instructions in Ubuntu 20.04, and the system had missing `gawk` so I had to install it.

Comment: In my case, bison was missing, so I had to install.

Comment: My version of `make` was too old. I followed [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31912233/how-to-update-make-3-81-linux) to update it, then I had to fix the `gmake` symlink to point to the new version at `/usr/local/bin/make`, and then I could install glibc as above.