# How can I get glibc 2.35 on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: glibc

I'd like to update to a 2022 version of glibc, at least 2.35. This seems to be available on Ubuntu 22.04, but how can I get it on 20.04?

Comment: the problem is that glibc is a system package, and a lot of things can break if you install the wrong version. what do you need it for?

Comment: @Esther I want those sexy new cutting-edge printf features. (It's not very important, but some code I wrote on a newer machine doesn't run on this one because it uses [this feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70993946/815612) which I didn't realize was new).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44710599/12642499 you can't replace the one you have, because many built-in binaries depend on it. But you can install the newer version from source in *some other location*, and patch your programs to use glibc from a non-default location. choosing a location for the install happens when you run `./compile --prefix=/path/to/new/glibc` in the source directory, you can pass it a flag `prefix` which will tell it where to install, and then `make` to compile and install glibc there.

Comment: Export the `LD_LIBRARY PATH` environment variable to point to the location of a newer lib.

Comment: @MarkHu, pardon my ignorance, with `PATH` you mean the `path-to-glibc-new-install/bin` directory from https://askubuntu.com/a/1345783/123217?

Comment: For me, glibc-2.35 on Ubuntu-20.04 crashes with `Segmentation Fault`, whether built from source or extracted from a newer-release `.deb`.

$ env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/me/Downloads/Build/glibc-2.35/glibc-build /bin/ls -F

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Answer (score 4):

You can use following commands to bring in newer version of glibc in `ubuntu 20.04`, but note that as it is a system package, upgrading it may impact your system.

```
apt-get install gawk bison gcc make wget tar -y
wget -c https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.35.tar.gz
tar -zxvf glibc-2.35.tar.gz && cd glibc-2.35
mkdir glibc-build && cd glibc-build
../configure --prefix=/opt/glibc
make
make install
```