# How to use glibc 2.33 when I already have glibc2.31

Tags: updates, gcc, glibc

To install [WRF-ARW](https://mahron.id/how-to-install-wrf-arw-on-macos-linux-wsl), I faced an issue with `glibc`. Like when I tried

```sh
gfortran TEST_1_fortran_only_fixed.f && ./a.out
```

I got the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/gcc@11/11.3.0/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11/liblto_plugin.so: error loading plugin: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/gcc@11/11.3.0/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11/liblto_plugin.so)
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have GLIBC 2.31,

```
ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9.9) 2.31
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty, not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
```

When I searched to update the lib, I got the warning alert from everywhere saying,

> The libraries shipped by glibc have a lot of reverse dependencies, and an upgrade would probably trigger a need to rebuild quite a few other packages.

Then what is the best possible solution to fix this issue? Any help will be appreciated. TIA

Comment: In fact, if I install it separately like [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1345783/1180075), then how to integrate it with my gcc@11?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS @David

Comment: You may want to investigate if 22.04 has the support you need.

Comment: It seems Ubuntu 22.4 have [glibc (2.35-0ubuntu3.1)](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/jammy/universe/proposed/glibc). Should I upgrade? Is it possible to face the issue then? @David

Comment: I think you mean 22.04 and it would seem to me that is the way to go. Check and see if the program you want to install can use 2.35

Comment: Is there any similar way to switch glibc like [GCC](https://archerfmy.github.io/2017/04/12/How-to-switch-your-gcc-g-version-in-ubuntu/)?