# How to install glibc 2.31 from source on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, compiling, gcc, glibc, binutils

I am trying to compile glibc 2.31 on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

I followed a [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345342/how-to-install-glibc-2-32-when-i-already-have-glibc2-31?newreg=634416f06af04e82b5a0a1cf8d571e11) as a template, which was incredibly helpful.

My issue is that there are undefined references when I run make:

```
...

make[2]: Entering directory '/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31/support'
gcc -Wl,-rpath-link=/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/math:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/elf:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/dlfcn:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/nss:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/nis:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/rt:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/resolv:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/mathvec:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/support:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/crypt:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/nptl -pie -Wl,-O1 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -o /home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/support/test-container    -Wl,-z,combreloc -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--hash-style=both /home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/csu/Scrt1.o /home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/csu/crti.o `gcc  --print-file-name=crtbeginS.o` /home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/support/test-container.o /home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/support/libsupport_nonshared.a -Wl,-dynamic-linker=/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-install/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2  /home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/libc.so.6 /home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/libc_nonshared.a -Wl,--as-needed /home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/elf/ld.so -Wl,--no-as-needed -lgcc  `gcc  --print-file-name=crtendS.o` /home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/csu/crtn.o
gcc -Wl,-rpath-link=/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/math:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/elf:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/dlfcn:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/nss:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/nis:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/rt:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/resolv:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/mathvec:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/support:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/crypt:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/nptl -pie -Wl,-O1 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -o /home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/support/shell-container    -Wl,-z,combreloc -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--hash-style=both /home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/csu/Scrt1.o /home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/csu/crti.o `gcc  --print-file-name=crtbeginS.o` /home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/support/shell-container.o /home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/support/libsupport_nonshared.a  -Wl,-dynamic-linker=/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-install/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2  /home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/libc.so.6 /home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/libc_nonshared.a -Wl,--as-needed /home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/elf/ld.so -Wl,--no-as-needed -lgcc  `gcc  --print-file-name=crtendS.o` /home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/csu/crtn.o
gcc -Wl,-rpath-link=/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/math:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/elf:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/dlfcn:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/nss:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/nis:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/rt:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/resolv:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/mathvec:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/support:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/crypt:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/nptl -pie -Wl,-O1 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -o /home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/support/echo-container    -Wl,-z,combreloc -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--hash-style=both /home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/csu/Scrt1.o /home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/csu/crti.o `gcc  --print-file-name=crtbeginS.o` /home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/support/echo-container.o /home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/support/libsupport_nonshared.a  -Wl,-dynamic-linker=/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-install/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2  /home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/libc.so.6 /home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/libc_nonshared.a -Wl,--as-needed /home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/elf/ld.so -Wl,--no-as-needed -lgcc  `gcc  --print-file-name=crtendS.o` /home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/csu/crtn.o
gcc -Wl,-rpath-link=/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/math:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/elf:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/dlfcn:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/nss:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/nis:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/rt:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/resolv:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/mathvec:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/support:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/crypt:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/nptl -pie -Wl,-O1 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -o /home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/support/true-container    -Wl,-z,combreloc -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--hash-style=both /home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/csu/Scrt1.o /home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/csu/crti.o `gcc  --print-file-name=crtbeginS.o` /home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/support/true-container.o /home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/support/libsupport_nonshared.a  -Wl,-dynamic-linker=/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-install/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2  /home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/libc.so.6 /home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/libc_nonshared.a -Wl,--as-needed /home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/elf/ld.so -Wl,--no-as-needed -lgcc  `gcc  --print-file-name=crtendS.o` /home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/csu/crtn.o
gcc -Wl,-rpath-link=/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/math:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/elf:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/dlfcn:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/nss:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/nis:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/rt:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/resolv:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/mathvec:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/support:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/crypt:/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/nptl -pie -Wl,-O1 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -o /home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/support/links-dso-program    -Wl,-z,combreloc -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--hash-style=both /home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/csu/Scrt1.o /home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/csu/crti.o `gcc  --print-file-name=crtbeginS.o` /home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/support/links-dso-program.o -lstdc++ -lgcc -lgcc_s  -Wl,-dynamic-linker=/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-install/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2  /home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/libc.so.6 /home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/libc_nonshared.a -Wl,--as-needed /home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/elf/ld.so -Wl,--no-as-needed -lgcc  `gcc  --print-file-name=crtendS.o` /home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/csu/crtn.o
/home/user/binutils/binutils-2.32-install/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/libstdc++.so: undefined reference to `fstat64@GLIBC_2.33'
/home/user/binutils/binutils-2.32-install/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/libstdc++.so: undefined reference to `pthread_key_create@GLIBC_2.34'
/home/user/binutils/binutils-2.32-install/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/libstdc++.so: undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_unlock@GLIBC_2.34'
/home/user/binutils/binutils-2.32-install/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/libstdc++.so: undefined reference to `pthread_detach@GLIBC_2.34'
/home/user/binutils/binutils-2.32-install/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/libstdc++.so: undefined reference to `pthread_setspecific@GLIBC_2.34'
/home/user/binutils/binutils-2.32-install/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1: undefined reference to `_dl_find_object@GLIBC_2.35'
/home/user/binutils/binutils-2.32-install/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/libstdc++.so: undefined reference to `__libc_single_threaded@GLIBC_2.32'
/home/user/binutils/binutils-2.32-install/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/libstdc++.so: undefined reference to `pthread_join@GLIBC_2.34'
/home/user/binutils/binutils-2.32-install/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/libstdc++.so: undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_wrlock@GLIBC_2.34'
/home/user/binutils/binutils-2.32-install/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/libstdc++.so: undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific@GLIBC_2.34'
/home/user/binutils/binutils-2.32-install/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/libstdc++.so: undefined reference to `pthread_key_delete@GLIBC_2.34'
/home/user/binutils/binutils-2.32-install/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/libstdc++.so: undefined reference to `lstat@GLIBC_2.33'
/home/user/binutils/binutils-2.32-install/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/libstdc++.so: undefined reference to `stat@GLIBC_2.33'
/home/user/binutils/binutils-2.32-install/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/libstdc++.so: undefined reference to `pthread_once@GLIBC_2.34'
/home/user/binutils/binutils-2.32-install/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/libstdc++.so: undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_rdlock@GLIBC_2.34'
/home/user/binutils/binutils-2.32-install/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/libstdc++.so: undefined reference to `pthread_create@GLIBC_2.34'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [../Rules:215: /home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31-build/support/links-dso-program] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31/support'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:470: support/others] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/glibc/glibc-2.31'
make: *** [Makefile:9: all] Error 2
```

Originally, I tried with:

```
gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38
```

But, after failure I tried (and failed the same way) with:

```
gcc (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38
```

This procedure fails with glibc 2.31 and 2.32, but works for glibc 2.35.

Lastly, I actually read the INSTALL document, and I see that:

```
* GCC 6.2 or newer

     GCC 6.2 or higher is required.  In general it is recommended to use
     the newest version of the compiler that is known to work for
     building the GNU C Library, as newer compilers usually produce
     better code.  As of release time, GCC 9.2.1 is the newest compiler
     verified to work to build the GNU C Library.

     For multi-arch support it is recommended to use a GCC which has
     been built with support for GNU indirect functions.  This ensures
     that correct debugging information is generated for functions
     selected by IFUNC resolvers.  This support can either be enabled by
     configuring GCC with '--enable-gnu-indirect-function', or by
     enabling it by default by setting 'default_gnu_indirect_function'
     variable for a particular architecture in the GCC source file
     'gcc/config.gcc'.

     You can use whatever compiler you like to compile programs that use
     the GNU C Library.

     Check the FAQ for any special compiler issues on particular
     platforms.

* GNU 'binutils' 2.25 or later

     You must use GNU 'binutils' (as and ld) to build the GNU C Library.
     No other assembler or linker has the necessary functionality at the
     moment.  As of release time, GNU 'binutils' 2.32 is the newest
     verified to work to build the GNU C Library.
```

So, I built binutils 2.32 following the excellent advice of the accepted answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1446863/trying-to-install-gcc-8-and-g-8-on-ubuntu-22-04).

Then, I put that version of binutils at the top of my PATH variable, yielding the following results:

```
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 8.4.0-3ubuntu2) 8.4.0

ld --version
GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.32

as --version
GNU assembler (GNU Binutils) 2.32
```

And still, I get the same errors for undefined references... I am lost.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.